# Hadoop Ecosystem: Map Reduce needed for Pig/Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, apache-pig

There is a whole lot of hadoop ecosystem pictures on the internet, so i struggle to get an understanding how the tools work together.

E.g. in the picture attached, why are pig and hive based on map reduce whereas the other tools like spark or storm on YARN?

Would you be so kind and explain this?

Thanks!
BR

[haddop ecosystem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw9vW.png)

Comment: Your question is not consistent. _"Pig and Spark"_ vs _"Spark and Storm"_?!? Did you mean _"Pig and Hive"_?

Comment: Read about Hadoop V1 _(only MapReduce for resource allocation and execution logic)_ vs Hadoop V2 _(YARN for resource allocation, multiple exec frameworks like MR, Tez, Spark-on-Yarn, etc)_

Comment: Pig and Hive is what i meant! I'm sorry for this mistake!

Answer (score 1):

The picture shows `Pig` and `Hive` on top of `MapReduce`. This is because `MapReduce` is a distributed computing engine that is used by `Pig` and `Hive`. `Pig` and `Hive` queries get executed as `MapReduce` jobs. It is easier to work with `Pig` and `Hive`, since they give a higher-level abstraction to work with `MapReduce`.

Now let's take a look at `Spark`/`Storm`/`Flink` on `YARN` in the picture. `YARN` is a cluster manager that allows various applications to run on top of it. `Storm`, `Spark` and `Flink` are all examples of applications that can run on top of `YARN`. `MapReduce` is also considered as an application that can run on `YARN`, as shown in the diagram. `YARN` handles the resource management piece so that multiple applications can share the same cluster. (If you are interested in another example of a similar technology, check out `Mesos`).

Finally, at the bottom of the picture is `HDFS`. This is the distributed storage layer that allows applications to store and access data. It provides features such as distributed storage, replication and fault tolerance.

If you are interested in deeper-dives, check out the [Apache Projects](https://projects.apache.org/projects.html?category) page.